# GPIO Soundboard with just one button

Tags: python, gpiozero

i am trying to program a soundboard in python using gpiozero and a single button.
Every time you press the button it should play the next sound.
It almost works, but unfortunately not satisfactory yet.

Can you help me?

```
import pygame
from time import sleep
from gpiozero import Button
from signal import pause


pygame.init()

button = Button(4)

snd1 = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/test.wav")
snd2 = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/test2.wav")
snd3 = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/test3.wav")
snd4 = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/test4.wav")

while True:
    button.when_pressed = snd1.play
    button.when_pressed = snd2.play
    button.when_pressed = snd3.play
    button.when_pressed = snd4.play

pause()
```

Comment: What is 'not satisfactory' about it?

Comment: it does not cycle through the sound files correctly. Maybe it is because the button is not debounced correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

button.when_pressed should really be assigned once for simplicity. I've created a function playFile() to cycle through the sound files to be played.

Try the following:

```
import pygame
from time import sleep
from gpiozero import Button
from signal import pause

def playFile():
    global sndPos
    print('playFile',sndPos)
    pygame.mixer.stop()
    snds[sndPos].play()
    sndPos += 1
    if sndPos>3:
        sndPos = 0

pygame.init()

sndPos = 0
snds = [pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/test.wav"),
        pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/test2.wav"),
        pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/test3.wav"),
        pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/test4.wav")]
button = Button(4)
button.when_pressed = playFile

pause()
```

Comment: Wow thanks! I'm really new into python. Will try it right now